# How do I merge all the Pdf files in a folder together into one PDF File such that there will be a blank Page after each file

Tags: java, pdf, merge, itext

Good day, Please I want to merge all the PDF Files in a folder into a Single file. But I want the new file to be in such a way that in the Merged File created, there will be a blank page after each of the files have been written. 
Below is my code which already do the merging. But no Blank page in between the Files in the Merged file created.

```
public static void mergePDFs(String directory, String targetFile) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    File dir = new File(directory);
    File[] filesToMerge = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        public boolean accept(File file, String fileName) {
            System.out.println(fileName);
            return fileName.endsWith(".pdf");
        }
    });
    Document document = new Document();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\LAWAL\\Desktop\\pdfs"+targetFile);
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
    document.open();

    for (File inFile : filesToMerge) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile.getCanonicalPath());
        copy.addDocument(reader);
        document.newPage();
        reader.close();   
    }
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: How about creating a temporary PDF with a single empty page first and then adding that document before each PDF from the folder except the first.

Comment: Please, how will I do that?